# Is it OK to assume mouse click count is 1 even if MouseEvent.getClickCount returns zero inside mouseReleased?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Ugh! I logged this [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8218421) in 2019 and completely forgot about it. It's still open. Nobody cares.

Most of the time, the following code behaves as expected. That is, when a row's checkbox is clicked once, then MouseAdapter.mouseReleased will print a MouseEvent.getClickCount of 1. I'm testing on Java 17.0.2.

But on some machines, it prints 0 often enough that I suspect a bug or a misinterpretation of something I read or did not read at all. Is there anything wrong with my expectation that click count should always be >= 1 within mouseReleased?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
   public Test() {
      Object[] cols = {"Id", "Boolean"};
      Object[][] data = {
         {"1", false},
         {"2", false},
         {"3", false},
         {"4", false},
         {"5", false}
      };
      JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {
         public Class getColumnClass (int column) {
            return column == 0 ? String.class : Boolean.class;
         }
         public void setValueAt (Object obj, int row, int col) {
            super.setValueAt(obj, row, col);
            System.out.println(String.format("row=%d col=%d", row, col));
         }
      });
      table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent ev) {
            // I argue this should never print 0 but it does sometimes.
            System.out.println("ev.getClickCount() = " + ev.getClickCount());
         }
      });
      table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
      getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            Test frame = new Test();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(150, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with this code.

Comment: Neither can I on my 2019 MacBook Pro running Sonoma but my colleague who has an "identical" one can. It's odd. That's why I'm wondering if I misunderstood the javadoc.

Comment: I can readily get zero on Sonoma 14.2.1 with % ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-21/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21+35-2513)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-2513, mixed mode, sharing) -- as long as I move the mouse pointer while clicking.

Comment: (and the clickCount is already zero in the native callback, `CPlatformView.deliverMouseEvent`, so hard to debug)

Comment: Ah, moving the mouse after pressing. That's sounds deviously familiar. I now need an antacid.

Comment: @tgdavies It's a contradiction for JTable to change a JCheckBox's state and then fire mouseReleased with a clickcount of zero.

Comment: If the down and up locations are both in the checkbox then the state changes. If they are in different checkboxes then it doesn't -- that seems okay. Why look at mouse events if you're interested in checkbox state changes?

Comment: Good question. It's about undo and redo to mimic how google mail handles checkboxes. If you hold the shift key and click, then all boxes are checked between the box you're on and the previous one that was checked. Undoing and redoing that requires some extra code. To handle, say, undo, for a shift-click, then you have to receive an event to cover that.